# Is there a better way to handle filters?

Tags: api, spring-boot, jax-rs

JAX-RS with SpringBootApplication.

I am building an API, and I want to make it is available for the users to use filters when they pull data. If they do a GET request to :

```
http://localhost:8100/apis/employee/?firstName=john&lastName=doe
```

The API will return one or more results that meet those requirements. 
I also want the ability that they use only one of the parameters (firstName or lastName). 
I was able to write the code and it works just fine, however for only two parameters and I already have three possible combinations (three query methods on my API).

```
 firstName = NULL && lastName = NULL (getAllEmployees case)
 firstName != NULL && lastName = NULL
 firstName = NULL && lastName != NULL
 firstName != NULL && lastName != NULL
```

This is how my GET method on employeeResource file looks like:

```
@GET
@QueryParam("{firstName}, {lastName}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response getEmployees(@QueryParam("firstName") String firstName, @QueryParam("lastName") String lastName) {

    List<Employee> employeeList;

    if(firstName != null && !firstName.isEmpty() && lastName != null && !lastName.isEmpty()) {

        employeeList = employeeRepository.findByFirstNameAndLastName(firstName, lastName);
    }
    else if(firstName != null && !firstName.isEmpty()) {
            employeeList = employeeRepository.findByFirstName(firstName);
    }
    else if (lastName != null && !lastName.isEmpty()) {
        employeeList = employeeRepository.findByLastName(lastName);
    }
    else {
        employeeList = (List<Employee>) employeeRepository.findAll();
    }

    if (employeeList.size() == 0) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
    }
    return Response.ok(employeeList).build();
}
```

And this is how my employeeRepository file looks like:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Employee, Integer>{
    List<Employee> findByFirstName(String firstName);
    List<Employee> findByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName, String lastName);
    List<Employee> findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

If I add a third parameter the possible combination scenarios would now be 8 so I will need to define 8 query functions on `employeeRepository` and you can imagine what happens if you have 10 possible parameters to search.

Is there any better way to implement this and not have to define all these methods??

I don't mind writing them, I just don't want to do something that is not the best way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more generalized find method in your repo you can use [The specification pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern). Here's an [article](https://thinkinginobjects.com/2012/08/26/dont-use-dao-use-repository/) that implements the specification pattern in java. If you want a more generalized filter at the REST endpoint, you can take a look at how OData formats their query string filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can write customized query on EmployeeRepository like below

@Query(" select e from Employee e where (:firstName is null or e.firstName=:firstName) AND (:lastName is null or e.lastName=:lastName) ")
List findByDifferentParams(@Param("firstName)String firstName, @Param("lastName)String lastName);

You can add additional parameters if needed.